# 94 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo

Tags: engine, jeep, idle, stall, grand-cherokee

My '94 Jeep seems to want to stall out at red lights and stop signs. It runs fine otherwise. However, upon cranking first thing of the day I have to let it idle for maybe five minutes before driving.

Comment: Which fuel does it use?

Comment: @HandyHowie - I would bet gas (petrol), but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Might be something with the idle sensor.

It can be a clogged catalytic converter. The problem can also be caused by a clogged or stuck EGR valve.

I have seen both clogged catalytic converter and EGR valves as a common thing that causes this problem.

An O2 sensor can be malfunctioning or be broke.

The transmission fluid level may be low.

Since the vehicle is from 1994 it should be the first standard of On board diagnostics (OBD-I).

The OBD-I system should have the engine light or another flashing light tell you info by blinking. The number of times the light flashes should tell you something in the manuals list of codes.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an automatic transmission.

Cold idle in park should be about 2K-2.5K, cold idle in drive should be about 1K-1.2K, warm idle in park should be about 900-1.1k, warm idle in drive should be about 600-750.  Your symptoms sound to be either a dirty throttle body, or a bad Idle Air Control Valve (IACV).

You can clean the throttle body by removing the air cleaner hose so you can see the butterfly valve.  Spray the edge of the valve with carburetor cleaner.  Open the valve by hand, and clean the buildup that has formed around the edge of the valve.

If the idle speed is not higher when the engine is cold, then the IACV is likely the cause.  This valve is located on the throttle body.

Some hacks/work arounds.  You can 'two foot it' by having one foot on the brake and another on the gas to keep the RPM up.  Your throttle body MIGHT have an minimum idle screw that you can turn to raise the minimum idle RPM.